# Configure/compile mod_php (PHP 5.2.17 for Apache 2.2.17) with "Thread Safety" disabled

Tags: multithreading, apache, thread-safety, mod-php, zend-optimizer

My Linux distribution is RedHat / CentOS 5.x i386/x86_64.

I'm using custom compiled Apache version 2.2.17 (both worker and prefork) modes with mod_php (PHP 5.2.17) custom compiled too.

phpinfo() page shows "Thread Safety" is 'enabled'.

My problem is latest ZendOptimizer version 3.3.9 doesn't provide thread safe extensions (_ts.so) anymore. So it is required to disable "Thread Safety" in PHP.

How can I configure (*.ini options) or compiling (configure options, make flags, etc.) mod_php with Thread Safety disabled